# Browser IE11 JavaScript Let [...document.querySelectorAll Syntax Error

Tags: javascript

I am receiving a syntax error and my page is blowing up in IE11. It works in chrome and firefox.

It says the syntax error is on this line `let checkboxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox].required')];`

Can Internet Explorer not read JS like this?

```js
$("#Main").show();
// Set up a blur event handler for each text field
$('.form-control:not("#BusinessName")').on("blur", function(evt) {
  let count = 0; // Keep track of how many are filled in

  // Loop over all the text fields
  $('.form-control:not("#BusinessName")').each(function(idx, el) {
    // If the field is not empty....
    if (el.value !== "") {
      count++; // Increase the count
    }
  });
  console.log(count);
  // Test to see if all 3 are filled in
  if (count === 3) {
    $("#contactinformation").prop("checked", true); // Check the box
  } else {
    $("#contactinformation").prop("checked", false); // Uncheck the box
  }

  checkCheckboxes();
});

let checkboxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox].required')];
let checkCheckboxes = () => document.querySelector('#printpage').disabled = checkboxes.some(check => !check.checked);
checkboxes.forEach(check => check.addEventListener('input', checkCheckboxes));
checkCheckboxes();

$(document).on('click keyup', '#printbtnhack', function() {
  if (document.querySelector('#printpage').disabled) {
    alert("Please check required fields");
  } else {}
});

document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = formatAMPM();

function formatAMPM() {
  var d = new Date(),
    minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes(),
    hours = d.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getHours() : d.getHours(),
    ampm = d.getHours() >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am',
    months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
  return days[d.getDay()] + ' ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' ' + d.getFullYear() + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ampm;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ContactName">Contact name: <font color="red">*Required</font></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactName" id="ContactName" size="40" maxlength="120" value="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="BusinessName">Business name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="BusinessName" id="BusinessName" size="40" maxlength="120" value="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ContactEmail">Email address: <font color="red">*Required</font></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactEmail" id="ContactEmail" size="40" maxlength="80" value="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ContactPhone">Phone number (business hours): <font color="red">*Required</font></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactPhone" id="ContactPhone" size="40" maxlength="50" value="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="headline">
    <h2>Checklist</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <p><strong>Check applicable boxes, print and send each item in with paperwork.</strong><span id="InstructionsSelect" class="labelspace noprint"><strong class="icon-question"></strong></span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="contactinformation" id="contactinformation" class="required" disabled /> Contact information
        <font color="red">*Required</font><span id="ContactSelect" class="labelspace noprint"><strong class="icon-bubble"></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="proofidentification" id="proofidentification" class="required" /> Identification document
        <font color="red">*Required</font><span id="IdentificationSelect" class="labelspace noprint"><strong class="icon-bubble"></strong></span>
        <!--<cfinclude template="../../includes/proofidentificationtip.cfm">-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="businessproofidentification" id="businessproofidentification" /> Proof of business verification <span id="BusinessSelect" class="labelspace noprint"><strong class="icon-bubble"></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="poa" id="poa" /> Power of attorney document - <a href="forms/poa.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 82053</span></a><span id="POASelect" class="labelspace noprint"><strong class="icon-bubble"></strong></span>
        <!--<cfinclude template="../../includes/poatip.cfm">-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="certificatetitle" id="certificatetitle" /> Application for Duplicate Certificate of Title - <a href="forms/duplicatetitleapp.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
        <cfif isDefined( "session") AND structKeyExists(session, 'checkout') AND structKeyExists(session.checkout, 'info') AND ( (structKeyExists(session.checkout.info, 'andor_1') AND session.checkout.info.andor_1 eq "And") OR (structKeyExists(session.checkout.info,
          'bandor_1') AND session.checkout.info.bandor_1 eq "And") )>

          <strong>- All signatures are required.</strong>
        </cfif>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="odometerreading" id="odometerreading" /> Current odometer reading and date read <strong>OR</strong> Mileage recorded as exempt
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="proofresidency" id="proofresidency" /> Proof of Manatee County Residency document <span id="ResidencyDocumentSelect" class="labelspace noprint"><strong class="icon-bubble"></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="proofaddress" id="proofaddress" /> Proof of address change - if applicable
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="liensatisfaction" id="liensatisfaction" /> Lien Satisfaction - if applicable
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="transactionsummary" id="transactionsummary" /> Transaction Summary - <a href="summary.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="feesbreakdown" id="feesbreakdown" /> Estimate of fees - <a href="forms/FeesBreakdown.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a><span id="FeeEstimateSelect" class="labelspace noprint"><strong class="icon-bubble"></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="money" id="money" /> Check or money order <span id="CheckOrMoneySelect" class="labelspace noprint"><strong class="icon-bubble"></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        *For a list of all other forms not listed above that may be applicable - <a href="https://www.flhsmv.gov/resources/forms/all-forms/ " target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <br>
  <div>
    <button class="btn-u btn-u-orange" onclick="window.print(); return false;" name="printpage" id="printpage"><span name="printbtnhack" id="printbtnhack"><strong class="icon-printer"></strong> Print Checklist</span></button>
  </div>

</form>

<span id="time"></span>
```

Comment: hmm apparently not ie11 either

Comment: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ would a compatability table help?

Comment: IE11 knows only ES5, the most of the newer JS is not supported.

Comment: It might be that IE11 can understand let, but not the spread syntax.

Comment: @Teemu it does support some ECMAScript 2015 syntax.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, kinda, IE knows the `let` keyword, but it behaves like `var` in IE.

Comment: @Teemu not according to the table. `let` and `const` are block scoped... I didn't know that

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to add an element with id=time

Comment: I updated my answer to handle your HTML. It is much simpler and more important has consistent use of jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. HTML5 required will stop a submission if you submitted the form. No need to test if the required checkboxes are checked.
2. jQuery has the tools you need anyway
3. I removed the "prtbtnhack" Please let me know what it solved

```js
$("#Main").show();
// Set up a blur event handler for each text field
const $req = $('input.form-control.required');
$req.on("blur", function() {
  // Test to see if all 3 are filled in
  let count = $req.filter(function() {
    return this.value !== ""
  }).length
  $("#contactinformation").prop("checked", count === $req.length); // Check the box
  checkCheckboxes();
});
const $chk = $('input[type=checkbox].required');
const checkCheckboxes = function() {
  let count = $chk.filter(function() {
    return this.checked
  }).length;
  console.log(count,$chk.length)
  $('#printpage').attr("disabled", count != $chk.length)
};
$chk.on("click", checkCheckboxes)
checkCheckboxes();

$('#printpage').on("click",function() {
  checkCheckboxes(); // added here since the auto checking is not triggering the change in IE
  if ($(this).is(":disabled")) {
    alert("Please check required fields");
  }
});

$("#time").html(formatAMPM());

function formatAMPM() {
  var d = new Date(),
    minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes(),
    hours = d.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + d.getHours() : d.getHours(),
    ampm = d.getHours() >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am',
    months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
  return days[d.getDay()] + ' ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' ' + d.getFullYear() + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ampm;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ContactName">Contact name: <font color="red">*Required</font></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm required" name="ContactName" id="ContactName" size="40" maxlength="120" value="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <div class="form-ghttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/59754958/browser-ie11-javascript-let-document-queryselectorall-syntax-error/59755085#roup">
        <label for="BusinessName">Business name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="BusinessName" id="BusinessName" size="40" maxlength="120" value="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ContactEmail">Email address: <font color="red">*Required</font></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm required" name="ContactEmail" id="ContactEmail" size="40" maxlength="80" value="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ContactPhone">Phone number (business hours): <font color="red">*Required</font></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm required" name="ContactPhone" id="ContactPhone" size="40" maxlength="50" value="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="headline">
    <h2>Checklist</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <p><strong>Check applicable boxes, print and send each item in with paperwork.</strong><span id="InstructionsSelect" class="labelspace noprint"><strong class="icon-question"></strong></span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="contactinformation" id="contactinformation" class="required" disabled /> Contact information
        <font color="red">*Required</font><span id="ContactSelect" class="labelspace noprint"><strong class="icon-bubble"></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="proofidentification" id="proofidentification" class="required" /> Identification document
        <font color="red">*Required</font><span id="IdentificationSelect" class="labelspace noprint"><strong class="icon-bubble"></strong></span>
        <!--<cfinclude template="../../includes/proofidentificationtip.cfm">-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="businessproofidentification" id="businessproofidentification" /> Proof of business verification <span id="BusinessSelect" class="labelspace noprint"><strong class="icon-bubble"></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="poa" id="poa" /> Power of attorney document - <a href="forms/poa.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 82053</span></a><span id="POASelect" class="labelspace noprint"><strong class="icon-bubble"></strong></span>
        <!--<cfinclude template="../../includes/poatip.cfm">-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="certificatetitle" id="certificatetitle" /> Application for Duplicate Certificate of Title - <a href="forms/duplicatetitleapp.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
        <cfif isDefined( "session") AND structKeyExists(session, 'checkout') AND structKeyExists(session.checkout, 'info') AND ( (structKeyExists(session.checkout.info, 'andor_1') AND session.checkout.info.andor_1 eq "And") OR (structKeyExists(session.checkout.info,
          'bandor_1') AND session.checkout.info.bandor_1 eq "And") )>

          <strong>- All signatures are required.</strong>
        </cfif>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="odometerreading" id="odometerreading" /> Current odometer reading and date read <strong>OR</strong> Mileage recorded as exempt
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="proofresidency" id="proofresidency" /> Proof of Manatee County Residency document <span id="ResidencyDocumentSelect" class="labelspace noprint"><strong class="icon-bubble"></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="proofaddress" id="proofaddress" /> Proof of address change - if applicable
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="liensatisfaction" id="liensatisfaction" /> Lien Satisfaction - if applicable
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="transactionsummary" id="transactionsummary" /> Transaction Summary - <a href="summary.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="feesbreakdown" id="feesbreakdown" /> Estimate of fees - <a href="forms/FeesBreakdown.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a><span id="FeeEstimateSelect" class="labelspace noprint"><strong class="icon-bubble"></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="money" id="money" /> Check or money order <span id="CheckOrMoneySelect" class="labelspace noprint"><strong class="icon-bubble"></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        *For a list of all other forms not listed above that may be applicable - <a href="https://www.flhsmv.gov/resources/forms/all-forms/ " target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <br>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-u-orange" onclick="window.print()" id="printpage"><strong class="icon-printer"></strong> Print Checklist</button>
  </div>

</form>

<span id="time"></span>
```

Comment: @DavidBrierton I figured it out. I change from arrow to function and forgot to return the test

Comment: I’ll check tomorrow

Comment: In the mean time change to `<button type="button" class="btn-u btn-u-orange" onclick="window.print()"`

Comment: It works in yours but for some reason wont work in mine. But thank you for your time and answer

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

IE doesn't support for spread syntax.

[image]